# Jquery Autocomplete Suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I’m working on a project, and they are using the following for the search functionality: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

I need to modify the Js because of accessibility issues; When using an iPhone, if you are using the keyboard and type “done” to close it the suggestion box closes too.
I need it to stay visible until the user clicks on any part of the page or selects one of the suggestions.

For desktop, if you tab it closes too, but it should stay opened until the user clicks outside the input or selects one suggestion.

Thanks in advance

I had tried to modify the case for key.Tab and the blur event